# Use named slots in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Is it possible to use `named slot` in Nuxt3?

I want to create a `reusable component` named "blue" like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button>
      <slot name="title">
    </button>
    <div>
      <slot name="content" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then in my home page for example I do:

```
<Blue>
  <v-slot title>
   <h1>Title of my article</h1>
  </v-slot>
  <v-slot content>
   <p>Read this interesting story</p>
  </v-slot>
</Blue>
```

Is something like this possible in Nuxt3? Whats the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you call the named slots on your home page is incorrect. You are missing the `v-slot` directive or the shorthand of the v-slot `#` See more about named slots in vue [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots)

I created an example for you based on your question.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-jnw7km?file=app.vue

This is how you call the named slots on your page.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <TheBlue>
      <template #title>
        <div>Hello World</div>
      </template>
      <template #content>
        <div>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
          accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam
        </div>
      </template>
    </TheBlue>
  </div>
</template>
```